# Truth table to Boolean Expression

Tags: education, boolean-algebra, boolean

Truth table to Boolean Expression.

This image belongs to my project for the university assignment, I am totally stuck with this, please help if you can.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $F=\overline A\,C+A\,\overline C=A\oplus C\,.$

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't know where to start and just want a method that will give you a valid answer, but not the best one, I got this for you :

Each time you see a 1 in the F column, you take each variable of the A, B, and C columns and associate them with an AND(.). To do so, if, for example, A is set to 1, you'll just write A. If B is set to 0, you'll write B', which means NOT(B).

And each time you do this, you need to separate each group of AND with an OR(+)

For your exercise, it goes :

> A'.B'.C + A'.B.C + A.B'.C' + A.B.C'

And, as Angelo remarked, you could also see that F only depends on A and C (B can be 0 or 1, it doesn't matter).

Comment: You did not explain when we have to write the negation of a variable (‘). Moreover, you wrote A.B.C’ twice and forgot A’.B’.C

Comment: Thanks, my bad.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections ! I have just upvoted you.